# Link shop page to external link in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, affiliate

i'm using shopkeeper theme in wordpresse, and i have only affiliate products on my website, so i want to send visitors directly to the external website if they click on a product in the shop page.
I've found similar questions in the forum but it didn't worked for me.
I heard that there are plugins to do it but i dodn't find them.

Anyone has a trick please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your website link and can you clear bit more?

Comment: an external website link?

Comment: Are you using woo commerce ?

Answer (score 1):

In single product page you have to select "External / Affiliate product" in product data section and then enter the external URL. In this case when someone clicks on your products they will be redirected to the external link you have assigned to each product. You can use [WooCommerce External Product New Tab](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-external-product-new-tab/) plugin to open the links in a new tab.